# -XX:+UseCompressedOops does not work in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

My Java (64bit) version information is as below:

```
D:\workspace\s3-jerome\Voice\nlp>java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

My application has a lot of instances, therefore it consumes plenty of memory if each reference occupies 8 bytes. So I want to use the -XX:+UseCompressedOops to force JVM to compress OOP. In eclipse, I have added -XX:+UseCompressedOops in the VM Arguments in run configuration.

But when I profile my program with VisualVM 1.3.7, I still get the result that size of each reference is 8 bytes.  The instance size of the following class is still 32!

```
public class AcLinkedList<E> {
    private E element;
    private AcLinkedList<E> next;

    public AcLinkedList(E element) {
       this.element = element;
       next = null;
    };

    .......
}
```

Anybody knows where is the problem?

Comment: `UseCompressedOops` is turned on by default. So `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` is basically a no-op.

Comment: So why, for example, I have 1,257,084 instance of the above class, and it consumes 40,226,688 bytes of memory, which means each instance occupies 32 bytes - 2 machine words for the header (2 * 8 bytes), and 2 reference pointer (2 * 8 bytes)?

Comment: I would expect it to use 24 bytes, not 32, on a 32 bit hotspot (or with compressed oop). Try running with `-XX:-UseCompressedOops` and see if your program uses more memory (it should) - maybe with an os tool as opposed to visual VM.

Comment: When I ran with -XX:-UseCompressedOops, the result is the same - still 32 bytes for one instance.  A bug for my java.exe - build 1.7.0_09-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `UseCompressedOops` is enabled by default on HotSpot 7 when appropriate (heap size is not too large).
2. JVisualVM does not take that setting into account and reports erroneous data.
3. You can convince yourself of the above by running a trivial Java program and measuring heap occupancy with `runtime.freeMemory()` and `runtime.totalMemory()`.

Comment: VisualVM shows that each instance of the above class AcLinkedList<E> occupies 32 bytes (16 for the header and 16 for the 2 reference attributes). I did not use -Xmx to assign more 32G memory to the program.

Comment: Hi @Marko Topolnik, do you know which Java profiler can take that setting into account and report real data?  I tried NetBeans IDE, it reports the same results.

Comment: NetBeans just uses VisualVM internally. Anyway, my finding was about an array of references; your report may actually be right. In addition to pointer size there are also data alignment concerns which determine the object footprint.

Comment: Also I don't think this is about VisualVM, it just calls a JMX method which reports this.

Comment: VisualVM analyses a heap dump, which is not the heap memory but a certain file format describing the heap’s content. But implementation details like the object header and the actual reference size are not included in this file, so VisualVM, or any heap dump analysis tool in general, has no chance of reporting the actual in-memory object size. Related article: [What Heap Dumps Are Lying To You About](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/heapdump-is-a-lie/).